# Facebook omniauth rails redirect to url, where user click facebook button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, devise

My problem:
I add facebook omniAuth by this guides (http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/). omniAuth work, but I need redirect user after sign_in to url, where user click facebook button.

In OmniauthCallbacksController I have method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.email_verified?
   super resource
 else
  finish_signup_path(resource)
end
```

end

When I change 'super resource' to 'profiles_path', It is redirect me to profiles page.

How to fix redirect to current page?

Comment: not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect the user to the URL where he clicked the Facebook button:

```
    redirect_to request.referer
```